# Vuforia is not rendering real world - Camera not rendering real world

Tags: unity, c#, vuforia

I follow this guide ([How-to-build-an-ar-android-app-with-vuforia-and-unity](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-build-an-ar-android-app-with-vuforia-and-unity/)) but added my own mobile picture in database (as a marker) so that I could see animated object on my mobile and i am able to run my app but camera is not rendering the real world object in scene. instead animated object showing only.
what i am doing wrong?

[image]

Remember vuforia doesn't recognize my web-cam profile and apply default profile on it.(Is this a problem )